# jQuery play Audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

So i have been doing some JavaScript and is currently learning jQuery. Time to time i get a bit confused by how jQuery does things compared to JS.

Got an HTML audio tag that looks something like this:

```
<audio id="audio" src="audio.mp3"></audio>
```

With JS i simply play it with:

```
document.getElementById('audio').play();
```

So i figured, doing the same with jQuery would just be:

```
$('#audio').play();
```

That doesn't work, instead i have to write it like this:

```
$('#audio')[0].play();
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code :

```
$('#audio').play();
```

gives you back an array of elements that match the query selector wrapped with jQuery functions, this is how jQuery works, in your case it will give an array with one element .

the .play function is not a jQuery function and works directly on the html element, thus, you need to go to the first element in the jQuery array and then use the .play function

Comment: Oh right, so it's because .play() is a pure JS function.. Thanks.